# Querying MorphToMany Relation Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel-5, eloquent

The thing I want to get from the database is that get all the posts with the data which will identify whether the post is liked by the auth()->user() or not. Most probably via count.

**App\Post**

```
public function likes()
{
    return $this->morphToMany('App\User', 'likeable');
}
```

**App\User**

```
public function likePosts()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Post', 'likeable')->withTimestamps();
}
```

**Likeables Table**

```
Likeables table has ('user_id', 'likeable_id', 'likeable_type')
```

I tried using orWhereHas

```
$posts = Post::with( ['user', 'tags', 'category'])->orwhereHas('likes', function($q) {
                    $q->where('user_id', auth()->id());
                })->latest()->withoutTrashed()->paginate(10);
```

But with about query I am only getting those posts which the user has liked. I want to get all posts and a check whether the post is liked by the user or not

I came across **whereHasMorph** but it was only for morphTo and not for morphToMany.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: @m_____ilk Yes, check the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@m____ilk I was able to solve this but creating a mutator:

```
public function isLiked()
{
    return $this->likes()->where('user_id', auth()->id())->count() > 0;
}
```

I ran a loop on the posts and attached a custom attribute to a single post based on the mutator.

```
$posts = Post::with( ['user', 'tags', 'category', 'post.user', 'post.tags', 'post.category'])->latest()->withoutTrashed()->paginate(10);

foreach ($posts as $post) {
    // Mutator Condition
    if ($post->is_liked) {
        // Custom Attribute
        $post->isLiked =  1;
    } else {
        $post->isLiked =  0;
    }
}
return $posts;
```

Comment: but in the case, i think you are running a query every time you call the function. i think it would be better to just join the tables when querying for users at first place.

Comment: Correct, I am claiming it to be a perfect solution. My first approach was to solve it via query but was unable to do that so this loop approach.

Answer (score 0):

In laravel 9 I did something like:

```
        $posts = Post::with( ['user', 'tags', 'category', 'post.user', 'post.tags', 'post.category'])
            ->withCount([
                'likes',
                'likes as is_liked' => function($q) {
                    $q->where('user_id', auth()->id());
                }
            ])->latest()->withoutTrashed()->paginate(10)
```